# How to resize the UITableViewCell based on size of image to be inserted?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my tableview, I have one section, and in that section there are two rows.
The first row contains the name of an image and the second row contains the actual image. When inserting the image, I want to resize the cell based on size of that image. I tried out with cell frame and size, but it's not working.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cells are laid out by the `UITableView`, you can't resize the cells directly.

You have to implement `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` in your [`UITableViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a)

Comment: we can resize the height using this method but how do we resize width, is it possible?

Comment: You'll have to resize the width of the tableView then, you can't change the width of a cell directly.

Comment: I guess the UITableView is already full width, so you can try embedding a `UIScrollView`, but that might not work, and I don't think that would please the user.  


If I were you I'd rather just use it as a preview and add a view option on tap, which would bring up the image viewer à la Photos app.